# Get actual type of variant data in dbus message

Tags: c, systemd, dbus

To do some pre-verification of received property set messages I need to get the type of the message data and compare it to the type of the property.

When I try to peek the type (using `sd_bus_message_peek_type`) it returns `"v"` which is the signature of variant. Is it possible to get the signature of the actual data wrapped in the variant? And how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variant is a *container* so one needs to enter that container to get the actual type.

Entering the container is done with [`sd_bus_message_enter_container`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_bus_message_enter_container.html).

Once the container is entered, the next data to read is the variant wrapped value.

---

Note that the pre-verification step can be done by the call to `sd_bus_message_enter_container` itself.

The `type` argument is the type of the property, and if it doesn't match the type of the message data then `sd_bus_message_enter_container` will return `-ENXIO`.